# Все ли знаки расставлены правильно?

Tags: пунктуация

**"Все, что ни делается, - к лучшему".**

Answer (score 1):

Знаки расставлены верно. Тире заменяет сказуемое ВЕДЁТ (или ДЕЛАЕТСЯ) в главном предложении. Запятыми выделяем придаточное предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Знаки расставлены вполне правильно, но тире здесь - интонационное, его можно и не ставить